# merging two dataframes with same variable names and (mostly) different na's

Tags: r

I have a situation where I have three dataframe. Using the dummy data below, the dataframes are set up as follows:

- df has an ID variable and a number of additional variables
- df1 has an ID variable to match df and information for varX_J where X
  is 00:19 (as characters), and J is a description for the variable
  name. The first three letters stay the same (var) for all variables
- df2 is the same as df1, with different information.

I need to merge df1 and df2 with df, while merging the data in the columns. df1 and df2 have the same observations. They *should* have different information (e.g, if there is a value for ID 1 in var09_married in df1, then there shouldn't be information in that same cell in df2. However, the data is messy and there are probably places where this isn't true.

To create this dummy data, I have the following script:

```
library('dplyr')

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:20),
                 og_var1 = sample(c(1:50), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 state = sample(c(1:52), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 race = sample(c(1:5), 20, replace=TRUE)
                 )

df1 <- left_join(data.frame(id = (1:20)), data.frame(
                  id = c(3,6,9,12),
                  var09_married = c(1,NA,2,1),
                  var09_happiness = c(1,NA,3,2),
                  var10_married = c(NA,1,2,2),
                  var10_happiness = c(NA,5,2,5)), by=c("id"))

df2 <- left_join(data.frame(id = (1:20)), data.frame(
                  id = c(3,6,11,15),
                  var09_married = c(NA,1,1,1),
                  var09_happiness = c(NA,3,3,2),
                  var10_married = c(1,NA,2,1),
                  var10_happiness = c(2,NA,4,4)), by=c("id"))


df <- left_join(df, df1, by=c("id"))
df <- left_join(df, df2, by=c("id"))
```

What I want is to merge this information together without duplicating the columns. If there is information in df1 and df2 in the same place (e.g., id3 has information for var10 in both df1 and df2), then I want to have the information from df1 in the final dataframe. But I'd also like to create a flag if this information is dropped. So the final dataframe should look like:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), og_var1 = c(6L, 4L, 33L, 7L, 
37L, 16L, 34L, 42L, 37L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 24L, 33L, 30L, 2L, 20L, 
29L, 33L, 47L), state = c(2L, 35L, 11L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 40L, 39L, 
28L, 13L, 5L, 26L, 28L, 15L, 13L, 31L, 43L, 25L, 16L, 28L), race = c(5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 5L), var09_married = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
2, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var09_happiness = c(NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), var10_married = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 
2, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var10_happiness = c(NA, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rows_patch` instead of joining:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |>
  rows_patch(df2, by = "id") |>
  right_join(df, by = "id")
```

From the documentation `?rows_patch`:

> works like `rows_update()` but only overwrites `NA` values

This means that if there are values in `df1` they will remain. Where there are `NA` in `df1` and values in `df2` then those values will be "patched" (i.e. updated with values from `df2`).

However, depending on your needs you might consider using `rows_update` which will update the entire row in `df1` with a row from `df2` if matched.

Comment: Hi @LMc - another wrinkle to add (though maybe I should make this a separate question) - is there a way to pick values from df1 half the time and df2 the other half? Basically, if we have two lists and there are some errors in each, and we're splitting the difference on where they overlap..

Comment: @tchoup I am sure what you want to do is possible. It would be helpful if you posted a new question with representative data.