# joining two dataframes in a complicated way

Tags: r

I have two datasets that *should* have incomplete complimentary information, but has errors, and I need to combine them into the main dataframe "df". In the dummy data below, for ID's 1:20, I should have repeating variables for different years. In df1, these data have the prefix "acs", and in df2, these data have the prefix "pcs". It looks like this:

```
library('dplyr')

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:20),
                 og_var1 = sample(c(1:50), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 state = sample(c(1:52), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 race = sample(c(1:5), 20, replace=TRUE)
)

df1 <- left_join(data.frame(id = (1:20)), data.frame(
  id =              c(3,6,9,12),
  acs09_married =   c(1,NA,2,1),
  acs09_happiness = c(1,NA,3,2),
  acs10_married =   c(NA,1,2,2),
  acs10_happiness = c(NA,5,2,5)), by=c("id"))

df2 <- left_join(data.frame(id = (1:20)), data.frame(
  id =              c(3,6,11,15),
  pcs09_married =   c(NA,1,1,1),
  pcs09_happiness = c(NA,3,3,2),
  pcs10_married =   c(1,2,2,1),
  pcs10_happiness = c(2,5,4,4)), by=c("id"))
```

Theoretically (but not actually), if ID x has data for year y and variable z in df1, then that ID should not have a value in df2. But there are cases where this is not the case and the ID has data in same columns. What I want to do is join df1 and df2 into the main df.

What I want to do is create a new set of variables with the prefix "apcs" followed by the year and variable name, like in df1 and df2. If there is information in either df1 or df2, I want to pull from that dataframe. If there is information in both df1 and df2 in the same place then I want to pick information from one of the two dataframes randomly.

I have tried to do this overly complicated thing where I combined df1 and df2 into df, and I'm trying to create a loop that has conditional requirements on how to create the new variable and that loops through the years and the different variables. But I didn't even get the first bit working of if they both have information, pick one randomly. And I think there probably has to be an easier way to do this. Here's where I've gotten:

```
df <- left_join(df, df1, by=c("id"))
df <- left_join(df, df2, by=c("id"))

df$random <- sample(0:1, size=nrow(df), replace =TRUE)

years=c("09", "10")

list <- colnames(df %>% select(contains(c("var", "prcs"))))
list <- sub(".*_", "", x)     
list <- unique(x)
list

for(x in years){
  for(j in list){
  df <- df %>% mutate(paste0("apcs",x,"_",j) =
                        ifelse(
                          !is.na(get(paste0("acs",x,"_",j))) &
                          !is.na(get(paste0("pcs",x,"_",j))), ifelse(random = 1,
                                                                     get(paste0("acs",x,"_",j)),
                                                                     get(paste0("pcs",x,"_",j))), NA
                        )
                      )
  }
}
```

Any advice?

*Related post where I tried to do this in a way that just privileged one dataset[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324874/merging-two-dataframes-with-same-variable-names-and-mostly-different-nas/76324967?noredirect=1#comment134732431_76324967)*

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to pivot the dataset such that you have a single `acs` and `pcs` column, then combine these with a `mutate` and pivot the data back to the required shape.  Here I've only kept the `apcs` values, but you could easily also keep the original data by changing the last `values_from` to `c(acs, pcs,apcs)`.

If anybody knows an easier way to do the `case_when` bit I'd be glad to hear it.

```
merge(df1, df2, by="id") |> 
  pivot_longer(-id , names_pattern = "([a-z]*)([0-9]*)_(.*)", names_to = c("survey","year", "var"), values_to = "score") |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols=c("id", "var", "year") , names_from="survey", values_from = score) |> 
  mutate(apcs = case_when((!is.na(acs))& is.na(pcs) ~ acs , 
                           is.na(acs)&!is.na(pcs) ~ pcs ,
                          (!is.na(acs))&(!is.na(pcs)) ~ ifelse(runif(length(acs))>0.5,acs,pcs),
                          .default=NA)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id , names_from=c(var, year), values_from = apcs)


# A tibble: 20 × 5
      id married_09 happiness_09 married_10 happiness_10
   <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1         NA           NA         NA           NA
 2     2         NA           NA         NA           NA
 3     3          1            1          1            2
 4     4         NA           NA         NA           NA
 5     5         NA           NA         NA           NA
 6     6          1            3          1            5
 7     7         NA           NA         NA           NA
 8     8         NA           NA         NA           NA
 9     9          2            3          2            2
10    10         NA           NA         NA           NA
11    11          1            3          2            4
12    12          1            2          2            5
13    13         NA           NA         NA           NA
14    14         NA           NA         NA           NA
15    15          1            2          1            4
16    16         NA           NA         NA           NA
17    17         NA           NA         NA           NA
18    18         NA           NA         NA           NA
19    19         NA           NA         NA           NA
20    20         NA           NA         NA           NA
```

Here's the full thing in case you'd rather have that:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="id") |> 
  pivot_longer(-id , names_pattern = "([a-z]*)([0-9]*)_(.*)", names_to = c("survey","year", "var"), values_to = "score") |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols=c("id", "var", "year") , names_from="survey", values_from = score) |> 
  mutate(apcs = case_when((!is.na(acs))& is.na(pcs) ~ acs , 
                           is.na(acs)&!is.na(pcs) ~ pcs ,
                          (!is.na(acs))&(!is.na(pcs)) ~ ifelse(runif(length(acs))>0.5,acs,pcs),
                          .default=NA)) |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id , names_from=c(var, year), values_from = c(acs,pcs,apcs))

# A tibble: 20 × 13
      id acs_married_09 acs_happiness_09 acs_married_10 acs_happiness_10 pcs_married_09 pcs_happiness_09 pcs_married_10 pcs_happiness_10 apcs_marr…¹ apcs_…² apcs_…³ apcs_…⁴
   <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 2     2             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 3     3              1                1             NA               NA             NA               NA              1                2           1       1       1       2
 4     4             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 5     5             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 6     6             NA               NA              1                5              1                3              2                5           1       3       2       5
 7     7             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 8     8             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
 9     9              2                3              2                2             NA               NA             NA               NA           2       3       2       2
10    10             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
11    11             NA               NA             NA               NA              1                3              2                4           1       3       2       4
12    12              1                2              2                5             NA               NA             NA               NA           1       2       2       5
13    13             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
14    14             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
15    15             NA               NA             NA               NA              1                2              1                4           1       2       1       4
16    16             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
17    17             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
18    18             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
19    19             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
20    20             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA             NA               NA          NA      NA      NA      NA
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​apcs_married_09, ²​apcs_happiness_09, ³​apcs_married_10, ⁴​apcs_happiness_10
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing forms - the actual dataset is just massive.

Comment: maybe. if this is important its a different question.